# How to correct "You exceeded the number of allowed tags of 10" when updating a vscode language extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have been updating my language extension for over 2 years without issue. Now I'm getting the error "You exceeded the number of allowed tags of 10". I don't have any "keywords" and I can't find anything in my package.json file that says "tags". How are the tags generated that are on my extension? How do I get them below 10?

- [My extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dehilster.nlp)
- [My package.json file](https://github.com/VisualText/vscode-nlp/blob/master/package.json)

I tried reducing the aliases in "languages" in my package.json file. That did not help.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be on purpose as stated here "[Marketplace will enforce extension keyword limit of 10](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/426)" but looking at the comments it appears that the change has introduced a bug "[Extension tags seem to be calculated incorrectly which blocks publishing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/815)"

The tags added by `vsce` to the extension manifest are the `keywords` you specified and some automatically generated tags based on [activation events, supported file extensions, and other things specified](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/blob/v2.15.0/src/package.ts#L562) in the `package.json`. These automatically generated tags go well over 10 for some extensions.

Until the `vsce` bug is fixed you can manually edit the `<extension>.vsix/extension.vsixmanifest` and remove the extra tags from the `<Tags>...</Tags>` section, then publish the extension using `vsce` or the web interface.